# Conditional where clause results in terrible performance Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

Firebird does not know how to execute a conditional where. Or that is what I think.

The First query returns values after 15ms.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
            A.MANID,
            A.DISNO,
            A.DISID
          FROM
            TABLEB B
            INNER JOIN TABLEA A ON (A.ITEM_ID = B.ITEM_ID)
          WHERE
             (
                (POSITION('%' IN :ISEARCH) = 0 AND B.CATID = :ISEARCH)
             )
```

This second query takes more than 40 seconds and all is about the OR condition.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
            A.MANID,
            A.DISNO,
            A.DISID
          FROM
            TABLEB B
            INNER JOIN TABLEA A ON (A.ITEM_ID = B.ITEM_ID)
          WHERE
             (
                (POSITION('%' IN :ISEARCH) = 0 AND B.CATID = :ISEARCH) OR
                POSITION('%' IN :ISEARCH) <> 0
             )
```

How can I tell firebird to behave in this type of situations?

Comment: What does the plan look like for each one?  That will be your biggest clue to what is going on.

Comment: The first query can be optimized if there is an index on `CATID`, but the second will be a natural scan. You might want to try two separate queries with a `UNION ALL` and see how that performs.

Comment: Yes, seems like Firebird can't handle the second query. The OR condition immediately throws out the index and goes for a full table scan, even in you force the plan. I had to approach my solution using multiple queries. Thanks for replying to this.

Comment: @user1791567 The query plan is decided on query prepare time, at that time the optimizer doesn't know what value the parameter :ISEARCH will have, so it simply doesn't consider the index, because if the second clause applies it can't use it.

Comment: What is this SQL trying to do? Are you trying to use `=` if there is no `%`, but use `SIMILAR TO` if `:ISEARCH` has a `%`? Because `SIMILAR TO` on a string with no wildcard should be the same as `=`.

Comment: Try using a `WITH` clause before your `SELECT` statement to grab the data you need from table `B`, then remove the `WHERE` clause from your  main `SELECT` statement and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A bit far-fetched and I'm not familiar with Firebird but for this particular case I'd suggest to try

```
(
    (POSITION('%' IN :ISEARCH) = 0 AND B.CATID = :ISEARCH) OR
    POSITION('%' IN :ISEARCH) <> 0
)
```

be written like

```
(
    (POSITION('%' IN :ISEARCH) <> 0 OR B.CATID = :ISEARCH) 
)
```

which might make more sense to the query optimizer?
It's still an `OR` and a lot of RDBMSs don't like `OR`s but it's worth a try...

Worst case you could try to split the statement into 2 separate queries that you `UNION ALL` together again where one handles `POSITION('%' IN :ISEARCH) <> 0` and the other `B.CATID = :ISEARCH`. The trouble with that approach might be doubled entries which will require filtering out again. (aka: a new can of worms...)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Mark R. gave us a hint why we shouldn't use that condition in a WHERE clause in Firebird. Also, we are on v.2.1 which lacks of some improvements that the v.2.5 brings to the table. Thanks again.